# Memory leak with KnockoutJS foreach binding

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, knockout.js, microsoft-edge

I run into an issue when running my KnockoutJS v3.4.2 (test) application in Google Chrome.
The memory usage of my page keeps increasing.

The test code is a very simple piece of code, that changes the items in an observable array every second:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>KnockoutJS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Foreach test</h1>
        <ul id="ul-numbers" data-bind="foreach: { data: listOfItems }">
            <li>
                <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/knockout.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var vm = {
    listOfItems: ko.observableArray()
};

window.setInterval(function updateList(){
    var array = [];

    for(var i = 0 ; i < 1000; i++){
        var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * 500);
        array.push(num);
    }

    vm.listOfItems(array);
}, 1000);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

**Memory usage:**

- In Firefox the memory usage doesn't increase: 
      start: **459.6 MB** ---> After +- 1 hour: **279.4 MB**
- In chrome the memory usage keeps increasing (memory of individual tab):
      start: **52.912 MB** ---> After +- 1 hour: **566.120 MB**
- In edge the memory usage also keeps increasing (memory of individual tab):
      start: **109.560 MB** ---> After +- 1 hour: **385.820 MB**

Am I doing something wrong in this code snippet? Or would this be a bug in Google Chrome or KnockoutJS?

Comment: What if you don't use `array` and instead call `vm.listOfItems.removeAll()` at the beginning of the function then `vm.listOfItems.push(num)` inside the loop (omitting the call to `vm.listOfItems(array)` at the end)?

Comment: Alternatively, you can try `vm.listOfItems(array.slice(0));` to prevent Knockout from preserving the reference to the original `array` and allow the GC to dispose it

Comment: Tested with the removeAll, but still the same behavior.

Comment: And sadly, also the same behavior, when I try your second comment

Comment: Tested too. Noticed that JS memory doesn't grow, only _private memory_ (I guess it's about DOM elements). So I think the problem is related to Chrome.

Comment: In which browser did you test? could you also test this in chrome, after a few minutes I already see the memory increase. I will do another test in Microsoft Edge, and check if the problem occurs.

Comment: I could also simulate this in Microsoft Edge (see updated answer). I will report an issue on github about this.

Comment: I have seen something like this before with chrome and knockout, can you take a heap snapshot and see some more information looking for the `Detached DOM tree` .. Should see some suspicious additions

Comment: That's the weird part, I don't see any additional items in the 'Detached DOM tree'. So this doesn't increase. I created a Github issue for this: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2223. There is an example project there, if you want to test it yourself.

Comment: I've tested in Chrome. You can right click in Chrome's Task Manager and select many other parameters to monitor. The parameter _JavaScript Memory_ does not increase during test. But _Private Memory_ do.

Comment: @f_martinez Indeed, I also noticed this. I thought this would be caused by a bug in Chrome, but because I can simulate this in Edge, so I'm not sure. Can you think of another reason why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this was a browser issue.

When I now run my test project the memory doesn't increase.
The test project can be found here: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2223

Solved in Google chrome version '58.0.3029.110'.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're replacing the array in the observable, they're still attached to the DOM. You would need to manually remove them prior to adding new elements to the array.

Something like this:

```
var vm = {
    listOfItems: ko.observableArray()
};

window.setInterval(function updateList(){
    var array = [];
    vm.listOfItems.removeAll();//<--this is the important line
    for(var i = 0 ; i < 1000; i++){
        var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * 500);
        array.push(num);
    }

    vm.listOfItems(array);
}, 1000);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

See #2 in this post: https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue, we have already tried that. (see comments on my question)